# Using Qt on Android installation

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, qt5

I am trying to install Qt 5.1 for Android, I am using steps described here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt5ForAndroidBuilding

I installed all the prerequisites (JDK, Android SDK, NDK, etc.). My problem is with step 4, I cannot download Qt 5 from the git repo (`git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git`).

Has somebody encountered the same problem?

I took another Qt 5 for Android directly from http://qt-project.org/downloads but it would not build. When I use step 4.4 (`configure -....`) I got the `The system cannot find the file specified: arch.cpp and arch.obj` error.

If you have a link or something that wil help me install Qt and deploy an app to Android please share.

Comment: What commands exactly did you execute? Also, why would you like to build it from scratch as opposed to installing the latest version from binary?

Comment: To rebuild the qt i used: configure -opengl desktop -xplatform android-g++ -openssl -developer-build -android-ndk d:/GitRepo/Resources/X2Go_Android/android-ndk-r8e -android-sdk d:/GitRepo/Resources/X2Go_Android/AndroidSDK/sdk
This gave me the error regarding arch.cpp not being found. I respected the steps described in the instalation link from official qt page.
I don't explicitly want to rebuild it, it will be great if I don;t do it, i just want to have qt creator with ssl working on android. i'm not interested in a specific release..any release would work.
Thank you

Comment: So, you would like to build Qt itself to get SSL support, right? I will update the title then since this seems to be leading point.

Comment: How did you try to clone the Qt 5 source btw?

Comment: Also, which compiler are you using on your Windows?

Comment: why did you accept an incorrect answer? You were asking about building Qt itself, and that answer is not about building Qt itself, but building applications with Qt.

Comment: It seemed that the problem was related mainly to what type of projet you select, regarding this the android options are available or not. Due to the fact that those android app ware not enabled i thought that the qt is not installed proprely and tried different qt installations. 1. was from gitorious but it didn't download the repo with the mentioned error and 2nd qt was the one for android but it didn't showed me the android options until I created a specific built in project. Following these project steps solved the enable android options from qt. Both answers are correct.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt Android version that you have download on qt-project is already built. You don't need to build Qt for Android, but build with Qt for Android. You just need to config Qt Creator to define SDK and NDK dirs. Follow this doc : http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-developing-android.html (main page : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/android-support.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5
cd qt5
perl init-repository --no-webkit

configure.bat \
    -developer-build \
    -xplatform android-g++ \
    -nomake tests \
    -nomake examples \
    -openssl
    -android-ndk D:/GitRepo/Resources/X2Go_Android/android-ndk-r8e \
    -android-sdk D:/GitRepo/Resources/X2Go_Android/AndroidSDK/sdk \
    -skip qttools \
    -skip qttranslations \
    -skip qtwebkit \
    -skip qtwebkit-examples-and-demos
make
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it seemed that I was too focused on rebuilding qt for android from scratch but it wasn't really necessary. I followed all the steps presented in the links provided and i succesfully installed a qt for android version. <br> I tryed for several times: git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5, always i get the error: cannot connect to gitorious... on error : "no error".

Comment: @Lucian: so what did you do wrong then? I thought you would have already tried to follow the official link?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt5ForAndroidBuilding This was the link I followed, and could not get the qt from the git, i always get the error: could not connect.On the other hand I took the qt for android and try to rebuild it with the config mentioned above, i got the arch.cpp missing error. Now, to make it work, i followed the links provided + set the app type as having"build in type", this triggered a new set of configs in "project" that i didn't had before. It was missleading because doc suggested to set x, y android config that was only present in creator IF app type was "build in types"

Comment: @Lucian: not sure I follow you, but it seems you should fix your gitorious issues. Many projects are hosted on there. Have you also tried the git clone command I wrote, i.e. git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git?

Comment: yes, I tried it and also used GUI git, also with clone action for the git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git. What I was trying to say is that I had Qt for android installed but the Android related options for the project was only available IF the project was created with new prj->quick app(built in types). I didn't figure out why git always says could not connect with error: no error.

Comment: @Lucian: You are saying gitorious does not work for you in general, including to get a tarball from there?