# Cross compilation NDK not found

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, qt5

I'm trying to install Qt5 Android and I face an issue while configuring :
The NDK is not found

### Environment

- Ubuntu 13.10
- Jdk 7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.10.1
- Java 1.7.0_51
- Qt-5.2.1

### Issue

Following instructions in the [Installing Qt for Android](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/androidgs.html) section the *configure* process failed.

```
./configure -developer-build -xplatform android-g++ -nomake tests -nomake examples -android-ndk $NDK -android-sdk $SDK
     -android-toolchain-version 4.8 -skip qttranslations -skip qtwebkit -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples -prefix $QT_OUTPUT_DIR

.....

Can not detect Android NDK toolchain. Please use -android-toolchain-version to specify
```

### Feedback

I've downloaded and extracted the required packages in a working directory **~/build/qt5-android** :

```
jeby6372@mercure:~/build/qt5-android$ ls
android-ndk-r8e  android-sdk-linux qt5
```

where of course :

- **android-ndk-r8e** is the NDK
- **android-sdk-linux** the Android SDK
- **qt5** the Android Qt5 sources

I've installed the required packages found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/linux-requirements.html)

```
sudo apt-get install sudo apt-get install libxcb-render-util0-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxrender-dev libxcb1-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-glx0-dev
```

for path setting I use these environments variables :

```
~$ export NDK=~/build/qt5-android/android-ndk-r8e
~$ export SDK=~/build/qt5-android/android-sdk-linux
~$ export $QT_OUTPUT_DIR=/opt/Qt5-Android
~$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

Can anybody help me ? thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Qt on Android installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031549/using-qt-on-android-installation)